# Facia prepared for install

Tags: painting

I am installing new facia it’s primed on the front should I prime and paint the back before as well as painting the front before installing?

Comment: What is it made of? If it is wood, that may be a good idea to help protect it. If it is some other material, particularly more water-resistant, it may not matter.

Comment: we can only guess the answer without more information, like what material is it? Painting before installing it is advisable

Answer (score 1):

Paint protects wood you can prime it now and paint it later or replace it sooner because it is not protected.
I paint all exposed wood or stain / seal cedar and redwood everything else gets paint

Answer (score 0):

Painting before installing is always easier, then painting after install.

Panting on the back is possible but might not be needed.

Since it is primed, one can assume it is wood or MDF material.

In that case at least priming on the back would be good, to prevent moisture absorption.